# Public IP address

Tags: azure

When we spin a new ubuntu block in azure, we get a public IP address for that block. I am working off a trial account. Does anyone know how many public IP addresses can Azure provide? Is there a limit. I believe there is a limit on AWS and then they want us to use some VPN like solution. Does this limit exist on Azure or not ?

Comment: This is a vendor-support question, not a StackOverflow question. Check with MS on the limitations of your trial account.

Comment: This is a valid StackOverflow question. From the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." as seen from http://stackoverflow.com/faq/. StackOverflow serves as a place to get quick quality answers and we should promote the sharing of knowledge, not hinder it.

Comment: By that logic, any Microsoft-technology related question is a vendor-support question, which would invalidate huge chunk of questions on this side....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a limit. You get a public IP address for every active deployment in a Cloud Service. Creating a Virtual Machine creates a Cloud Service behind the scene and puts an active deployment on it. That public IP address is guaranteed to not be changed while your deployment is there (not deleted). Whether that public IP address is shared with other deployment - I don't know (but my guess is - yes). By default there is a limit for the number of cloud services one can create. This limit depends on the type of subscription you have. So this is the kind of limitation there is in Azure.